# Hiding RadTimePicker using JQuery

Tags: jquery, telerik

I'm new to Telerik controls. I have Start Time and End Time UI controls using . I need to hide the **Start Time:** and **End Time:** picker controls using **Date Type:** RadComboBox selected value. Attached the image below.

[image]

I couldn't hide the RadTimePicker control using JQuery.

Can some one share your thoughts?

Regards,
Sriram!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
                var test = $find("<%= RadTimePicker1.ClientID %>");
                if (sender.get_selectedIndex() == 1) {
                    test.set_visible(false);
                }
                else {
                    test.set_visible(true);
                }

            }
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="ClientSelectedIndexChanged">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="show time" Value="1" Selected="true" />
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="hide time" Value="0" />
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
        <telerik:RadTimePicker ID="RadTimePicker1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadTimePicker>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```